# Kde funciona mal cuando cambio la forma de seleccionar los datos de un dataframe en R

Tags: r

estoy trabajando con una base de datos de observaciones de cetáceos en un archipiélago. Quiero calcular el área donde ocurren el 95% de las observaciones. Primero estaba dividiendo los datos por meses, y funcionaba perfectamente.

```
 Avistamientos_cetaceos_2001_2018 <- read_excel("C:/Users/ESTIMADO 
 USUARIO/Desktop/AZORES/Trabajo/Avistamientos_cetaceos_2001-2018.xlsx", 
                                           sheet = "Sheet1")

 Sights <- as.data.frame(Avistamientos_cetaceos_2001_2018)
 SightsMay <- Sights[Sights$month == 5,]

 SightsCoorMay <- cbind(SightsMay$longitude, SightsMay$latitude)

 SightsCoorMay <- as.data.frame(SightsCoorMay)

 kd2May <- ks::kde(SightsCoorMay, compute.cont=TRUE)


 contour_95May <- with(kd2May, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                       z=estimate, levels=cont["5%"])[[1]])

 contour_95dfMay <- data.frame(contour_95May)

 ggplot(data=SightsCoorMay, aes(V1, V2)) +
   geom_point(color="red") +
   geom_path(aes(x, y), data=contour_95May_DF) +
   theme_bw()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, la funcion kde selecciona bien el area que ocupa el 95% de las observaciones. Ahora bien, cuando hago lo mismo por año en vez de por mes, me selecciona un área minúscula.

```
Sights01 <- Sights[Sights$year == 2001,]

contour_9501 <- with(kd201, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                       z=estimate, levels=cont["95%"])[[1]])

contour_95df01 <- data.frame(contour_9501)

ggplot(data=SightsCoor01, aes(V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(color="red") +
  geom_path(aes(x, y), data=contour_9501_DF) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado todos los datos. Está todo correcto. Es la función que de alguna forma calcula ese área.

¿Alguna respuesta?

Comment: Por qué dices que el fallo está en KDE?

Comment: porque al hacer el kernel de las coordenadas, para algunos datos esta cogiendo un area que no es el 95% de las observaciones. He repasado el codigo y es que para algunos subsets coge unas areas que no tienen sentido